# FastCGI write system call to stdout (c)

Tags: c, apache, printf, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I am running apache2 with FastCGI and want to make a write syscall. Printf works but I'm looking to use write to optimize. Is this possible? The fastcgi documents and some other questions on the topic suggest you shouldn't mess with writing to stdout except using printf, but I haven't seen anyone explicitly say it. Further, the fastcgi dev kit code does have #defines for STDOUT, STDERR, and STDIN. I think this should be possible but am not seeing anyone do it.

Comment: `write` is not going to be much faster than `printf` as IO overhead limits the speed. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I agree with FUZxxl. I think a challenge will be generating enough data to make any measurable difference before you start getting blocked by network bandwidth. But it might be a fun experiment. Call ffush(stdout) before you start calling write(), in case anything is sitting in the stdio buffers. How are you going to measure and benchmark the differences?

Comment: Just to clarify: this is specifically for performance testing, so printf vs write might actually matter. "Generating enough data" will be taken care of, don't you guys worry about that ;)

Comment: I may be misinterpreting your question, but you can use `FCGX_PutS` or `FCGX_PutStr` given a `FCGX_Stream` obtained from your `FCGX_Accept_r`. All of which are defined in `fcgiapp.h`.

Comment: @jacob, this may work as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Following a LOT more testing and rummaging around the internets, I believe this solves my issue.
`FCGI_fwrite(str, sizeof(char), strlen(str), stdout);`

Just calling `write` did not work and using the `FCGI_stdout` file descriptor also did not work.